# Remove padding in sidebar, Streamlit

Tags: python, css, user-interface, streamlit

How to remove the top vertical padding in the default Streamlit sidebar?

Posting the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

```
st.markdown(" <style> div[class^='st-emotion-cache-10oheav'] { padding-top: 0rem; } </style> ", unsafe_allow_html=True)
```